# Search text and return range on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, range

The function I need is to search text and return DOM [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) object. I have tried:

1. The native `window.find()`. It returns the range object (`selection` `range`), which is what I want. However, the function seems very limited. E.g. I cannot manipulate the search starting point; and I cannot limit the search scope to a specific `html element`.
2. jQuery `:contains`. It gets the nodes containing the text. But how to get range out of the `nodes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of self-promotion, I've spent quite a bit of effort on this problem for my [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) library. The [TextRange module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) will do what you want and the [demo page](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/textrange.html) has an example of searching within page text.

Comment: Hi Tim. But it is two slow for large html files.Is there any other solution

Comment: @steo @dong@navin-gubta have you found any better solution?